# Vectorising .apply function to return 2 columns

Tags: pandas, vectorization, pandas-apply

How can I vectorise the following code (without changing the functions)

```
sms['Digit'] = 0
sms['URL'] = 0
###THE FOR LOOP IS MAKING MY CODE VERY SLOW
for i in range(len(sms)):
    sms['Message'].iloc[i],sms['Digit'].iloc[i] = nm.remove_numbers(sms['Message'].iloc[i]) 
    sms['Message'].iloc[i],sms['URL'].iloc[i] = nm.trim_urls(sms['Message'].iloc[i])
sms['Message'] = sms['Message'].apply(nm.stem)
sms.head()
```

where the functions `nm.remove_numbers` and `nm.trim_urls` are the following

```
# removes large numbers from sms text
def remove_numbers(message):
    # identifies number with digits in [4,25]
    number_re = "(?<!\d)\d{4,25}(?!\d)"
    numbers = re.findall(number_re, message)
    for number in numbers:
        message = message.replace(number, '')
    return message, numbers.__len__() > 0


# trims all urls in sms text down to their domain names
def trim_urls(message):
    # identifies if string is url
    url_re = 'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'  #a better version of this
    urls = re.findall(url_re, message)
    for url in urls:
        trimmed_url = url.split("//")[-1].split("/")[0].split('?')[0].replace('www.', '')
        message = message.replace(url, trimmed_url)
    return message, urls.__len__() > 0
```

Hence I return a pair of values from the functions and wish to unpack that pair and assign them to `sms['Message']` and `sms['Digit']` for the first function (both are similar).

I tried unpacking using `*` but that throws an exception. So does any explicit assignment like

```
sms['Message'],sms['Digit'] = sms['Message'].apply(nm.remove_numbers)
```

Is there some way I can get rid of my for loop, and vectorise my code? 
Of course if it can't be done, and my only option is to edit my main functions, then just help me with that option.

Comment: `apply` is **not** vectorized.

Comment: @QuangHoang is there some other method that is vectorised and will help me get the same effect im looking for?

Comment: Use [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) on the entire dataframe instead of parsing one at a time. These operations will be many times faster than `.apply` You can't vectorize your operation _and_ leave the functions as-is.